NoClassDefFoundError in networknt json-schema-validator in android 5.1
With the help of networknt json-schema-validator i'm trying to validate json schema. The below code is working fine in Android 11
    val mapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory())
    val jsonNodeReader = JsonNodeReader.builder().yamlMapper(mapper).build()
    val factory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V4) {
        it.jsonNodeReader(jsonNodeReader).build()
    }
    val config = SchemaValidatorsConfig.builder().build()
    val schema = factory.getSchema(schemaFile, InputFormat.YAML, config)
    val messages = schema.validate(yamlFile, InputFormat.YAML, Consumer { it.executionConfig.formatAssertionsEnabled = true })

but it doesn't work in Android 5.1. I'm getting the below error
Uncaught Exception in Thread ID: 1 - Thread name: main
         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/BootstrapMethodError;
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ExceptionUtil.isFatal(ExceptionUtil.java:51)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrowIfFatal(ExceptionUtil.java:31)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:70)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:402)
             at com.genedrive.print.SchemaValidator.validateSchema(SchemaValidator.kt:44)
             at com.genedrive.account.login.LoginFragment$onViewCreated$1.onClick(LoginFragment.kt:117)
             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

Below is the gradle file implementation of the library
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28

dependencies {
    implementation('com.networknt:json-schema-validator:1.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
    }
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0'
}

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Let me google that for you: https://rollbar.com/blog/java-no-class-def-found-error/

NoClassDefFoundError means the class was there when you compiled, but isn't there when you tried to run it. There are two main cases where you get this:

The JAR with the class is missing or you haven't added the location of the JAR to the runtime classpath.
A versioning error where you were developing to one version of Java/Android but tried to run on a different (typically earlier) version

The solution is simple: Find out why the class/JAR isn't there at runtime, and fix it, if possible.

There is no such possibilities, I just added the library dependencies in Gradle file. No jar got added manually to the project
